# Clone disk from cmd

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, disk-cloning, dism

Is there a way to clone a disk from the command prompt?

I know about programs like Minitool Partition Wizard which can easily perform a clone from within Windows itself, but at the moment I only have access to the prompt.

I'm inside the original Windows 10 and I have to perform the cloning to a completely empty disk inside the same device.

It seems that xcopy wouldn't work since I have to select the drive letter, while I have to copy multiple partition from disk 1 to disk 2.

I thought about creating an image using dism inside the new disk and then restoring it, but I don't know how to do it and I think that there are more efficient ways...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use CloneZilla then https://clonezilla.org/

Alternatively, you could download Hiren's BootCD although I think it's a bit out of date now. It has cloning tools included https://www.hirensbootcd.org/

Comment: I cannot open Windows... As said I need something from the command prompt

Comment: Do you not have access to another PC to create a clonezilla boot disk?